# Rvest html_nodes span div and Xpath

Tags: r, xpath, rvest

I am trying to scrape a website by reading XPath code.
When I go in the developer section, I see those lines:

```
<span class="js-bestRate-show" data-crid="11232895" data-id="928723" data-abc="0602524361510" data-referecenceta="44205406" data-catalog="1">
```

I would like to scrape all values for data-abc.
Let's say each element on the site is a movie, so I would like to scrape all data-abc elements for each movie of the page.

I would like to do so using Rvest package with R.
Below are two different attempts that did not work...

```
website %>% html_nodes("js-bestRate-show") %>% html_text()

website %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "js-bestRate-show") %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//div") %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//span") %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//data-abc")
```

Anyone knows how html_nodes and Rvest work?

Comment: Unless you're doing something complicated, CSS selectors are a lot simpler, e.g. `'<span class="js-bestRate-show" data-crid="11232895" data-id="928723" data-abc="0602524361510" data-referecenceta="44205406" data-catalog="1">' %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('span') %>% html_attr('data-abc')` Note you'll also need `html_attr` to get the attribute. `html_text` gets the text contained by a tag, e.g. `<p>some text</p>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The node is `span` with class `js-bestRate-show`. Everything else is an attribute. So you want something like:

```
library(rvest)
h <- '<span class="js-bestRate-show" data-crid="11232895" data-id="928723" data-abc="0602524361510" data-referecenceta="44205406" data-catalog="1">'

h %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes("span.js-bestRate-show") %>% 
  html_attr("data-abc")
```